# Sine Derivatives of High Orders

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, modular-arithmetic

I want to ask whether my answer, and assertions are true. I think that, for $n\ge0$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$:

- If $n\equiv1\pmod{4}$, then $\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}[\sin x]=\cos x$
- If $n\equiv2\pmod{4}$, then $\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}[\sin x]=-\sin x$
- If $n\equiv3\pmod{4}$, then $\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}[\sin x]=-\cos x$
- If $n\equiv0\pmod{4}$, then $\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}[\sin x]=\sin x$

For my problem, to find $\dfrac{d^{87}}{dx^{87}}[\sin x]$, I came up with $-\cos x$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct---you can easily prove this claim by induction, taking $n = 0, 1, 2, 3$ as base cases.

Comment: Yeap! $87=84+3$!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Complex analysis even suggests that this is also closely tied to the fact that $i^n=\{i,-1,-i,1\}$, i.e. has 4 possible outcomes (depending what n (mod 4) is), as the answer by egreg beautifully elaborates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the derivatives are correct. Just use induction with four cases for the induction step.

Alternatively, observe that $f(x)=e^{ix}$ has $f'(x)=ie^{ix}$ and, by induction on $n$,
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[e^{ix}]=i^ne^{ix}
$$
Since $i^4=1$, we have

- $i^n=i^0=1$, if $n\equiv0\pmod{4}$,
- $i^n=i^1=i$, if $n\equiv1\pmod{4}$,
- $i^n=i^2=-1$, if $n\equiv2\pmod{4}$,
- $i^n=i^3=-i$, if $n\equiv3\pmod{4}$.

Now it's just a question of computing
\begin{align}
i^0&(\cos x+i\sin x)=\phantom{-}\cos x+i\sin x\\
i^1&(\cos x+i\sin x)=-\sin x+i\cos x\\
i^2&(\cos x+i\sin x)=-\cos x-i\sin x\\
i^3&(\cos x+i\sin x)=\phantom{-}\sin x-i\cos x
\end{align}
and equating the real and imaginary parts.